# Automatic scrolling of textbox choppy

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, scroll

I am redirecting CMD output to a multi-line textbox, I'm trying to auto-scroll down using the following code:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
textBox1.Refresh();
```

However it's really choppy looking, by that I mean, each time a line comes in, it positions the scroll bar at the top of the textbox, then to the bottom, it's hard to describe so I made a .gif of it happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/swppy.gif

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same purpose I use RichTextBox:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(cmdOutputMsg + "\r\n");
richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

In this way the new text is always added at the end of the existing text, and with ScrollToCaret the focus remains on the last inserted text.

I think with normal TextBox will work in the same way.

Comment: AppendText seemed to do the trick, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!